# Android ContentResolver - save photo metadata

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-camera2, android-contentresolver

I'm creating a photo making app using Camera2 API.
I would want to set additional information to the photo (date, location), but I'm getting "Uknown URL" exception.

When i comment out contentResolver, photo is saved, but is lacking any additional information, and I need to have access to the location - I will be filtering gallery to only those which are in close proximity.

```
internal class ImageSaver(
    private val image: Image,
    private val file: File,
    private val watermark: Bitmap,
    private val mContext: Context
) : Runnable {

    private val saveImageExecutor: Executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    override fun run() {


        val jpegByteBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer
        val jpegByteArray = ByteArray(jpegByteBuffer.remaining())
        jpegByteBuffer.get(jpegByteArray)

        val width = image.width
        val height = image.height
        saveImageExecutor.execute {
            val date = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val location = getLocation(mContext)
            val longitude = location?.longitude ?: 0.0
            val latitude = location?.latitude ?: 0.0

            // watermark
            val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
            options.inMutable = true
            val original =
                BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegByteArray, 0, jpegByteArray.size, options)
            val overlayed = overlay(original, watermark)
            val watermarkedByteArrayOS = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            overlayed!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, watermarkedByteArrayOS)

            val watermarkedByteArray = watermarkedByteArrayOS.toByteArray()
            Log.d(TAG, "saving pic meta-data")
            val values = ContentValues()
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE, file.name)
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, file.name)
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, file.path)
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN, date)
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.WIDTH, width)
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.HEIGHT, height)
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LONGITUDE, longitude)
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LATITUDE, latitude)

            Log.d(TAG, "LON: ${values.get(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LATITUDE)}")
            Log.d(TAG, "LAT: ${values.get(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LONGITUDE)}")
            var output: FileOutputStream? = null
            try {
                output = FileOutputStream(file).apply {
                    write(watermarkedByteArray)
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
            } finally {
                image.close()
                output?.let {
                    try {
                        it.close()
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
            mContext.contentResolver.insert(Uri.fromFile(file), values)

        }



    }
```

Output:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/(...)/DCIM/20200610165428492.jpg
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1831)
        at ...ImageSaver$run$1.run(ImageSaver.kt:86)
```

What should be the URI? Is there any better way to store location of a photo?

Comment: "What should be the URI?" -- one from a `MediaStore` collection. "Is there any better way to store location of a photo?" -- put the data in EXIF headers using `ExifInterface`, and let `MediaStore` get the data from the photo. As it stands, the data that you are trying to insert into `MediaStore` will get wiped out if `MediaStore` ever re-indexes the photo, if that data is not in the photo.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for responding! Also, my phone gallery is not picking up my folder (which is in android/data/..), what should I do so my phone treats my app as a media provider?

Comment: On Android 9 and below, if this is a photo, consider creating a subdirectory of DCIM and use that. You can get that directory via `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`. On Android 10+, you wind up using `MediaStore` somewhat differently, letting it give you a `Uri` that you can then write the photo into. [This sample](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos) demonstrates the basic process, though in my case I am downloading videos rather than working with photos.

Comment: `the data that you are trying to insert into MediaStore will get wiped out if MediaStore ever re-indexes the photo, if that data is not in the photo.`. @CommonsWare. I doubt that. The default Camera app on one of my devices puts location info in mediastore. Not in the exif of the image. I've never seen that info disappear.

Comment: @blackapps: That implies that `MediaStore` is doing basically a merge of the data, taking what is in the photo if it exists and keeping its own existing data for things that the photo does not specify. That is a wonderful implementation. But, I "have trust issues", so I'm concerned that it might not work that way for all pieces of data.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry for maybe asking trivial questions, but what is the easiest way of retrieving information that were put by ContentResolver? I would want to get from the put values longitude and lattitute. Should I use contentProviderClient? `myContext.contentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(Uri.fromFile(photos!![0]))`

Comment: @mintas123: Generally, I would use `query()` on `ContentResolver`.